# Restrict mainActivity to be accessible by other apps in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I have an app developed with flutter and I am wondering if it is possible - on Android - to restrict my Android mainActivity to be accessible from other apps.

On the iOS side, only by setting the "custom URL scheme" attribute is it possible to call the app from other apps. I would like to implement the same behavior on the Android side

Comment: You can set exported=false in the manifest for the activity.  That would prevent it from being launched by any other app.  However that won't work for your launcher activity-  the one that gets run when you tap on it in the apps list or a shortcut.  That has to be exported, because it has to be launched by another app (the phone's home page is an app, as is the list of apps on the phone).  So generally the main activity has to be exported although other activities can be private

Comment: So, if I understand, the solution could be to create another activity to be protected with exported=false ? there's not a system to create a list of allowed app?

Comment: No there is no system to create a list of allowed apps.  It's either exported or not.  Whether creating a second activity would help or not, I can't really tell.  I'm not sure what you're tying to accomplish by doing this.  It's extremely unusual behavior, it's really rare to use this functionality.

Comment: um I know it's very strange, but I just want to prevent my application from being opened by another one.

Comment: yes, but why?  Tell us why you want that, and we may be able to suggest better ways of accomplishing what you really want.  The idea of "don't let my app be launched by another" doesn't work when the ONLY way of launching an app on the OS is to be launched by another.

Comment: the app is part of a complex system, which also exposes rest services to other software houses. The exposed services, for many reasons, are different from those used by the app. some sh, however, have essentially used the app to get around this limitation, and this could be a problem, especially since you lose track of operations, which now seem to go only through the app

Comment: Sounds like you should be providing an SDK to provide those rest services to others rather than providing them through having your app installed.  But in any case preventing them from launching your app can't be done (you could at best limit them to launching your main activity) and doesn't seem likely to fix your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257205/discussion-between-second-and-gabe-sechan).